# iOS: How to open 0th Index of tabBarItem by clicking 3rd index of tabBarItem

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have 5 `tabBarItem` in my `UITabBarController` 
One scenario, I have to open First index of `UITabBarItem` by clicking third `UITabBarItem`

My approach as in below:

```
extension FiveTabbarController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {
    override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {

         if item == (self.tabBar.items!)[2] {
             tabBar.selectedItem = (self.tabBar.items!)[0] // ERROR
             self.selectedIndex = 0 // NOT WORKING
         } 

    }
}
```

> Error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
> 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason:
> 'Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.'

Kindly guide me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want your view controller's base class to be a UITabBarDelegate. If you were to do that, all of your view controller subclasses would be tab bar delegates. What I think you want to do is to extend UITabBarController

```
class FiveTabbarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {
```

then, in that class, override viewDidLoad and in there set the delegate property to self:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
    }
```

now this class is both a UITabBarDelegate (because UITabBarController implements that protocol), and UITabBarControllerDelegate, and you can override/implement those delegate's methods as desired, such as:

```
    extension FiveTabbarController: UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) {
       if let getSelectedIndex = tabBarController.viewControllers?.firstIndex(of: viewController), getSelectedIndex == 2 {
            self.selectedIndex = 0
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the behavior by doing:

```swift
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelect viewController: UIViewController) { 
    if selectedIndex == 2 {
        self.selectedIndex = 0
    }
}
```

The reason for the error is because you shouldn't modify the selectedItem, only the index. By modifying the index the tab bar controller will set the selectedItem.

*Edited*
Didn't notice you are using tabBar's method instead of tabbarcontroller's.

Comment: Is this working in ur end? Here, it is not working. Can u guide me on this ?

Comment: Yes., I too didn't notice, u have edited the answer. It is working fine.